# How is component inheritance done in Svelte?

Tags: javascript, svelte, svelte-component

I currently have a Modal.svelte component that uses native , I would like to create another component called ModalSheet.svelte whose parent is Modal.svelte.

Is this possible in Svelte without conflicts? Let's say I want to take advantage of all the functions already built into the parent component (Modal.svelte) in the child component (ModalSheet.svelte) and also add new functions in ModalSheet.

I also want to be able to use both  and  in the same page at the same time. I don't know to what extent it is possible.

Modal.svelte file:

```
<script>
  export let backdropClose;
  export let modalId;
  export let modalClass;
  export let labelledby;
  export let label;
  export let modal;

  let content;
  const isModal = typeof modal === "string" ? modal !== "false" : true;

  export function openModal() {
    if (content) {
      if (isModal) {
        content.showModal();
        return;
      }
      content.show();
    }
  }

  export function closeModal() {
    if (content) {
      content.close();
    }
  }

  function handleClick(event) {
    if (content && isModal && backdropClose === "true") {
      const rect = content.getBoundingClientRect();
      if (
        event.clientX < rect.left ||
        event.clientX > rect.right ||
        event.clientY < rect.top ||
        event.clientY > rect.bottom
      ) {
        content.close();
      }
    }
  }
</script>

<dialog
  aria-label={label}
  aria-labelledby={labelledby}
  id={modalId}
  class={modalClass || "ph-modal"}
  bind:this={content}
  on:click={handleClick}
>
  <slot />
</dialog>

<style lang="scss">
  dialog {
    border: 0;
    border-radius: 8px;
    background-color: #fff;
    &::backdrop {
      background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    }
  }
</style>
```

Comment: It is not done.  If you want to reuse code consider things like pulling out common functions or interfaces into `$lib` and leveraging `<slot>`s.

Answer (score 1):

There is no real inheritance if you want to use regular component syntax, only composition.
So the specialized modal can only internally use the generic modal.

You can can use `{...$$restProps}` to pass on any not explicitly set properties to the base component.
Events can be forwarded by just setting `on:event` without specifying a handler.

For functions you probably will have to wrap/re-export them, e.g.

```html
<script>
  // ...

  let modal;

  export function openModal() { modal.openModal() }
  // etc.
</script>
<Modal bind:this={modal} {...$$restProps}>
  <slot />
</Modal>
```

You could also export the internal modal instance as a property so it can be used more directly, though that breaks encapsulation.